# With SQL/TSQL, how can I use STUFF within this WHILE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a string, such as:

```
@String = 'filename.jpg##!!!##file description##|||##filename2.jpg##!!!##file description'
```

And then a loop, which I'll explain momentarily:

```
WHILE LEN(@String) > 0
    BEGIN
        set @filestring = LEFT(@String, CHARINDEX('##|||##', @String+'##|||##') -1)
        set @filename = LEFT(@filestring, CHARINDEX('##!!!##', @filestring+'##!!!##') -1)
        set @filedesc = RIGHT(@filestring, CHARINDEX('##!!!##', REVERSE(@filestring)) -1)

        UPDATE Table SET Description = @filedesc
        WHERE Filename = @filename

        set @String = STUFF(@String, 7, charindex('##|||##', @String+'##|||##'), '')

    END
```

This loop works fine until it reaches the end.

Example:

Pass 1:

```
WHILE LEN(@String) > 0
    BEGIN
        set @filestring = LEFT(@String, CHARINDEX('##|||##', @String+'##|||##') -1)
        -- 'filename.jpg##!!!##file description'
        set @filename = LEFT(@filestring, CHARINDEX('##!!!##', @filestring+'##!!!##') -1)
        -- 'filename.jpg'
        set @filedesc = RIGHT(@filestring, CHARINDEX('##!!!##', REVERSE(@filestring)) -1)
        -- 'file description'
        UPDATE Table SET Description = @filedesc
        WHERE Filename = @filename

        set @String = STUFF(@String, 7, charindex('##|||##', @String+'##|||##'), '')
        -- 'filename2.jpg##!!!##file description'   
    END
```

Pass 2

```
WHILE LEN(@String) > 0
    BEGIN
        set @filestring = LEFT(@String, CHARINDEX('##|||##', @String+'##|||##') -1)
        -- 'filename2.jpg##!!!##file description'
        set @filename = LEFT(@filestring, CHARINDEX('##!!!##', @filestring+'##!!!##') -1)
        -- 'filename2.jpg'
        set @filedesc = RIGHT(@filestring, CHARINDEX('##!!!##', REVERSE(@filestring)) -1)
        -- 'file description'
        UPDATE Table SET Description = @filedesc
        WHERE Filename = @filename

        set @String = STUFF(@String, 7, charindex('##|||##', @String+'##|||##'), '')
        -- 'filen'  <------ problem
    END
```

This method has worked for me in the past with no problems but only when using a single character as a delimiter.

So that last set @String should have made it an empty string but it grabbed some of the filename characters.

Comment: What are you trying to do and why in the world are you using a loop for this?

Comment: Trying to take a delimited string and process it so the data is normalized in SQL. Would you suggest a better method than LOOP?

Comment: Yes. A loop is a very slow and complicated way to do this. You need to use a string splitter. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last loop your `RIGHT(@filestring, CHARINDEX('##!!!##', REVERSE(@filestring))` 
evaluates as `RIGHT(@filestring,-1)` which is an invalid length for RIGHT.
One way to avoid this if you want to stay with loops could be to use:

```
WHILE CHARINDEX('##!!!##',@String) > 0
```

instead of

```
WHILE LEN(@String) > 0
```

Comment: Is there a better way to handle this than with looping? I thought this was faster than creating a temp table or other methods.

Comment: I don't think there is a better way than looping, assuming the value of @String is passed from the environment to the SQL Server. I can imagine an intricate way, involving a [common table expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx), but such a solution will probably be harder to understand for other programmers and I don't expect you'll gain much performance in an attempt to reduce the number of updates from once per loop to just one. What else would make it 'better'? Anyway, performance could benefit from an index on the field 'Filename'.

Comment: @R.Schreurs - a string splitter would be better than looping like this. See my link above.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm also looking at the string splitter, but this certainly did the trick. Had to fix another issue in my SP as well... The STUFF at the bottom of the loop was wrong.

Comment: @SeanLange, I think that depends on the _metric_ for goodness you use, but I've read your link with pleasure and it offers some nice algorithms. The OP introduced a bug when rewriting his solution to facilitate multi-character delimiters, which clearly illustrates it is better to reuse tested code than write your own. dbo.SplitStrings_CTE, e.g. is not very readable nor documented, so you would have to trust your case obeys input limitations, if any. Also, I would be reluctant to incorporate a CLR assembly just for string splitting.

Comment: The metric I use for goodness has two steps. First and foremost the results MUST be accurate and precise. The second is performance. Since I have more than 1 tested and true string splitter in my arsenal I would never allow a while loop doing this kind of thing row by row when a much faster set based approach is at my fingertips. My personal preference is the original Moden version (link is in the article attached). The purpose of the CLR option is that is the fastest, period. I agree it is a bit overkill for most situations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of doing this using the original Moden splitter referenced in Aaron's article (http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings). Here is the direct link. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

```
declare @String varchar(500) = 'filename.jpg##!!!##file 1 description##|||##filename2.jpg##!!!##file 2 description'

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Something') is not null
    drop table #Something

create table #Something
(
    MyFileName varchar(50),
    FileDescription varchar(50)
)

insert #Something (MyFileName, FileDescription)
select 'filename.jpg', '' union all
select 'filename2.jpg', ''

select * from #Something

set @String = REPLACE(REPLACE(@String, '##!!!##', '^'), '##|||##', '|')
select @String;

with MyUpdateValues as
(
    select
        MAX(case when x.ItemNumber = 1 then x.Item end) as MyFileName
        , MAX(case when x.ItemNumber = 2 then x.Item end) as FileDescription
    from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@String, '|') files
    cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(files.Item, '^') x
    group by files.ItemNumber
)

update s
set FileDescription = u.FileDescription
from #Something s
join MyUpdateValues u on u.MyFileName = s.MyFileName

select * from #Something
```